# this2.'function' is not a function - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array of items and I want to render them in view, so I use a function and called it from my render part as below :

after that on each item I have a touchableOpacity and a function. but when I touch them this error will show up:

**_this2.selectAvatarID is not a function**

I tried to use bind but it didn't work.
If you could please help me with some advices.
thanks.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);       
        this.state = {
            userID : 0,
            username: '',
            password: '',
            password2: '',
            email: '',
            loading: false,
            showAlert: false,
            alertType: true,
            alertMessage: '',
            emailVrified : '',
            isGuest : '',
            selectedAvatar: '',
        };        
        this._selectAvatarID = this._selectAvatarID.bind(this);
    }

_selectAvatarID = (xData) => {
         if(this.state.selectedAvatar == xData){
            this.setState({ selectedAvatar: '' });
         }else{
            this.setState({ selectedAvatar: xData });            
        }
     }

renderAvatars = () => {        
        let avatar = [];        
        Object.keys(avatars).forEach(function (key){           
            avatar.push(
                <TouchableOpacity key={avatars[key]} style={styles.avatarModalItems} onPress={() => this._selectAvatarID(key)} >
                    <Image source={avatars[key]}  style={{width:80, height:80}}/> 
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        }); 
        return avatar;
    }

render() {
return (
     <View style={styles.avatarModalView} >
         {this.renderAvatars()}                                
     </View>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that was because this part

```
Object.keys(avatars).forEach(function (key){
```

and in fact it needs to be like this :

```
Object.keys(avatars).forEach(key => {
```

can anyone explain me what is going on?

Comment: An arrow function (key => {}) inherits the “this” from the scope where a function (function(key) {}) creates a new “this” scope.